# Calculating Year-Over-Year Change and Other Summaries in {gt} Tables [r]

Tags: r, gt

I am creating summary tables for my data using the `gt` package.

Ultimately, I need three tables:

1. Values for groups (rows) by year (columns)
2. Percentage change over previous year `(column[n] / column[n-1] - 1)`
3. Cell's value as a percentage of total value for the year (all rows)

I have no issues with the first table.

```
    library(gt)

    # data for three groups over two years
    d <- data.frame(
      group = c("sg1","sg2","sg3","sg1","sg2","sg3","sg1","sg2","sg3"),
      year = c(2020L,2020L,2020L, 2019L, 2019L,2019L, 2018L, 2018L,2018L),
      value = c(1234, 4321, 12345, 1432, 4212, 13214, 1332, 4112, 13114)
    )

    #convert the data to a wide format with years as columns
    d.wide <- reshape(d[order(d$year, decreasing = FALSE),], 
              varying = list(as.character(2018:2020)),
              idvar = "group",
              timevar = "year",
              direction = "wide")

    # construct the gt
    my.gt <- gt(data = d.wide, rowname_col = "group") %>%
      tab_row_group(
        group = "Row Group A",
        rows = c("sg1","sg2","sg3")
      ) %>%
      fmt_number(
        decimals = 0,
        sep_mark = ",",
        use_seps = TRUE,
        columns = names(d.wide)
      ) %>%
      summary_rows(
        groups = TRUE,
        columns = names(d.wide),
        fns = c("Group Total" = "sum"),
        decimals = 0
      )
```

The code above creates the following table:

[image: gt table showing values by group / year]

This is a simplified but accurate illustration of what I am looking for. In the real data, there will be several row groups and several year columns. My solution needs to be flexible to accommodate a varying number of columns (i.e., hardcoding for a fixed number of years is not an ideal solution).

Where I am getting stuck is on Tables 2 and 3 which are calculated.  I can create a version of `d` that contains calculated values for each of the group/year values (and to clarify, this question is not asking how to calculate these in a data.frame); however, I would like the `summary_rows` (e.g. "Group Total") to also show the calculations for the `tab_row_group` (e.g. all rows within "Row Group A").

For Table 2 (percentage change over the previous year), the table would look like this (Note the omission of 2018 because no previous year exited to compare to.):

[image: gt table mock-up showing desired content]

The `gt` functionality allows you to use a user-defined function for the summary rows.

```
  summary_rows(
    ...
    fns = c("Group Total" = [USER FUNCTION]),
    ...
  )
```

But I cannot figure out how that might interact with an adjacent column's data, nor what that data might be if the table uses a data.frame containing pre-calculated percentages.

**Finally:** other than liking the feel and appearance of gt while creating Table 1, and the two days I've spent familiarizing myself with the package, I am open to other solutions.

My caveat to that is the exhibit will be exported to MS Word and converted to a pdf. My preference is a vector output (svg) or (as in my current gt_table workflow) html that may be pasted into the Word document. I know high-resolution bitmaps (i.e., png, jpeg, etc.) should in theory be sufficient quality; however, I have had frustrating experiences with bitmaps that include text in the past (fine in Word, but lost resolution when converting to pdf). While I initially considered html to be a workaround, I actually find I like the format because it gives me the flexibility to make minor tweaks to formats in the report if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Andrew

Comment: It may be easier to do this outside and create the `gt`.

Comment: For the rows sg1, sg2, sg3 I agree.  The summary row (Group Total),  generated by gt.  So if I generate outside of gt, I would probably calculate all rows (sg1, sg2, sg3, and Group Total) create a table with only data rows, then change the formatting on the "Group Total" row so it looks like a summary_row (despite being a regular data row). Thanks for the time you spent.

Comment: I was thinking of `d.wide2 <- {(d.wide[-1][-1] - d.wide[-1][-ncol(d.wide) +1])/(d.wide[-1][-ncol(d.wide) + 1])} %>% bind_cols(d.wide[1], .) %>% mutate(across(-1, ~ formattable::percent(.)))`

Comment: I took a slightly different approach: adding columns to the master file (`d` in my example) then selecting the column I want (i.e. sales or percentage change) when creating d.wide.  Either way, I have the outcome I was looking for, even if it is a workaround.

Comment: There are several ways to do this.  The base R method of subtracting equal sized dataset is straightforward